# Apache Commons Validator 1.6 API - RFC

Tags: email-validation, rfc, rfc822

What is the RFC number on which  Apache Commons Validator  1.6 API (org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator) for Email Validation is based?

I have choice to make if my existing validation should be migrated to okta (IAM) which is RFC 5322 based or use Apache Commons Validator  1.6. We were currently using Apache Commons Validator  1.4  but having some issues with some email format like domain name >3 characters.

The advantage of delegating to Okta i see is that okta will automatically comply with latest and greatest RFC # .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this see the Apache Commons Validator [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/package-summary.html#other.email):

> 4.7 Email Address Validation EmailValidator provides email address validation according to RFC 822 standards.